# Access ports with specific address

Tags: port-forwarding, pi-hole

I've set up Pi-hole to manage my network, and it is installed on a Raspberry pi 4 that already handles some stuff, for instance, an R-shiny server on port 3838 and a homeassistant installation on port 8123.

I want these services to be accessible through user-friendly addresses.

I added a local DNS entry so that `http://raspi.local` redirects to my raspberry pi, but I obviously have to add the port to the address for this to work.

I have very little knowledge of networks and maybe a little over my head here. I read everywhere that DNS has nothing to do with ports, neither `/etc/host`.

How could I access my services through pretty addresses such as `http://raspi.local/shiny` (port 3838) and `http://raspi.local/homeassistant` (port 8123)?

**EDIT - what I've tried so far:**

- in Pi-hole, setting an IP with the port after a `#` or a `:` " throws `Error while adding this custom DNS entry`
- looking up `mod_proxy` in Lighttpd configuration (`/etc/lighttpd/external.conf`) but with no sucess so far

Comment: I'd suggest looking into using a web server like nginx as a reverse proxy to handle any connections. You can then use proxy_pass to redirect connections to the correct port on localhost

Comment: I have no pi-hole at the moment (do not ask - just putting OS back on disk) so I'm not sure if this works.  Bit concerned you have used https - as the cert could break this if it does not handle sub-domains. You must have the pi-hole as your DNS then add a local entry such as http://pi-hole.raspi.local with an address as 127.0.0.1#5335 or http://shiny.raspi.local as 127.0.0.1#3838 - if that does not work replace the hash with a colon and if that does not work try replacing 127.0.0.1 with the address of the pi-hole followed by # port number or colon port number - let me know how you get on.

Comment: Its best to flush the DNS cache of any machine you are testing this from - do not uses th pi-hole for initial tests.  Proxy set-up depends on the pi-hole web server you installed it on...

Comment: @Andyroo Unfortunately, using `#` in IP causes errors in pi-hole

Comment: Did you replace with ':' and did that work if you did?

Comment: @Andyroo yes I did, as I stated in my edit

Comment: Sorry - only read the comment (blush) I'll see if I can set up a pi-hole and try a few things tonight - just having issues with ssh / washing up and doctors all at once!

Comment: @Andyroo No no no ... please don't suggest to use DNS domain **.local**. That is explicitly reserved for mDNS and should never occupied by other services. Beside other issues it is undefined that it can have subdomains. Some services may have problems with it (e.g. avahi)?

Comment: @Ingo sorry but your comment is a bit confusing, could you elaborate? This raspberry is not intended to be accessed outside my local home network so .local seems quite suited to my case. (not sure about subdomains but I wasn't going for it anyway)

Comment: @Ingo Well unless its changed in the last couple of months, the use of .local was still awaiting an answer as it has been for years.  Any service can be hosted on .local with no issues if it is LAN traffic only and in this case I'm following the Apple standard where services are advertised by bonjour against a .local name.  It also follows the questions request based on the raps.local server name.  RFC 6762 allows other services to resolve addresses as needed.  TBH - the whole .local mess needs kicking into touch and dear old MS need to update their docs :-)

Comment: @DanChaltiel Did you try sub-domains rather than your wish of \xxx?

Comment: @Andyroo as I told you, I cannot put any `#` or `:` in the IP address so I cannot try it. However, this is not what I want to do so I admit not putting much effort to try it further than that.

Comment: @David - You should not find mod_proxy as that's an Apache web server module.

Comment: @Andyroo thanks for trying to help me but please do a little research before telling things like this as there are quite a lot of comments already. There is a mod_proxy in lighttpd as well: [link](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModProxy).

Comment: It looks like pi-hole only takes ports on upstream DNS server addresses not local (found the original full article not just a reference post) - proxy may well be your only option.

Comment: @Andyroo I know you are aware of the problems with`.local` and we can discuss it forward and backward. But I mean it is bad practice to use a reserved item in particular it is known to make problems. Using it anyway will not reduce them especially if you already have problems. Just use a neutral domain and you are on the safe side, *localnet* or *mynet* or *mylocal* are also nice, isn't it? ;-)

Comment: @DanChaltiel *your comment is a bit confusing, could you elaborate?* - Please have a look at [Wikipedia - .local](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local). *This raspberry is not intended to be accessed outside my local home network so .local seems quite suited to my case* - but only if you do not "touch" it. It is exactly made to be usable out of the box (with mDNS) only on local networks. You cannot say "it is only used on my local network, so no problem".

Comment: @Ingo thanks, I understand better now. Rewrote it to `http://raspi.home`.